# How can I fix rendering problems with Sublime Text 2.02 on Google Hangouts?

Tags: macos, fonts, sublime-text-2

I am attempting to pair with someone using Google Hangouts and Sublime Text. He is using OS X Snow Leopard, and SublimeText 2.02. On his screen, the fonts look normal; on mine, they are rendered as an illegible combination of black on dark gray.  Has anyone seen and solved this problem?

Comment: Have you considered reporting this as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Do you experience the same with sublime text 3?
I know it is in beta, but they have improved the rendering and also it now has suport for high dpi on windows/linux and it may be that those 2 are the problems for you.